# Moving Background Image using :target

Tags: image, css, background, target

Is it possible to move the background image, using an anchor and the :target selector, a certain number or px every click?

HTML:

```
<div id="main_pic">pictures</div>
<a href="#main_pic">right</a>
```

CSS:

```
#main_pic {
    height: 750px;
    width: 491px;
    background-image: url(file:///Mac%20Drive/Users/ludicious/Websites/Jongbom/images/main_comic.png);
    background-position:0px 0px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    display: block;
}
#main_pic:target {
    background-position:+491px 0px;
}
```

I have +491px trying to move the image to the right that many px every click. I can move it once, but no more after that. Anyone know anything I can do?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible doing this using just CSS. You can set/unset an offset once (like you managed to do), but there is no way to add anyhting to this more than once without consulting JavaScript.

With the exception of some pseudo-selectors (one of which is :target, others are :hover and :active for example) and some Shadow DOM magic (mostly input elements) the DOM itself has hardly any notice of what a user is doing on a page. Instead, the browser relies on events that can be observed using JavaScript.

As a result, you will not be able to count the amount of clicks on the anchor, you can only see whether it's active or not. That is not enough to move the background more than once. I'm afraid you're going to have to use JavaScript for this.